# I do not understand. MainActivity label is application label

Tags: android

Manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme" >

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/yukleniyor" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
....
```

string.xml:

```
<resources>

<string name="app_name">Fıkralar 10000</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="yukleniyor">Lütfen Bekleyiniz. Yükleniyor...</string>
```

but my aplication name is "Lütfen Bekleyiniz. Yükleniyor..." 
I do not understand. MainActivity label is aplication label :S. 
MainActivity label changes, the application name is changing.
I applied what is written above. but not
What can I do. separate application label and MainActivity label to be separate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

< intent-filter > can have a label attribute. Using this, you can set a label(name) for the launcher icon, while still having the Activity with it's own title. Modify your manifest as follows:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
       android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/yukleniyor" >
    <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```